# SharePoint 2013 "Sites I'm following" Points to Wrong URL

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, distributedcache

I have 3 major site collections where 250 sites are housed inside of it. For example:

- https://Departments.internal.contoso.com
  https://Projects.internal.contoso.com
  https://Communities.internal.contoso.com

Recently i followed a site listed below:using follow funcationality provided in new sp2013 env.

I can see the url listed as below in "Sites I'm following" in My Sites

https://departments.internal.contoso.com/site/Area37

After couple of days i  came back to my Sites and clicked that same url, it now brings me to:
https://projects.internal.contoso.com/site/Area37

and gives http 404 not found error because that site doesnt exist.

So i unfollowed the site and refollowed again, it got fixed.

So this morning again i went to access such other site i experinced same behavior, url got changed.

Can anyone point me to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AAM to alias the web applications departments and projects or are they separate web applications? What zone is the URL or the My Site Host that you are having issues with? Are you seeing this behavior from different zones?